# How to fix? Full height <li>'s width not updating after vertical resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

**::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::UPDATE:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::**

I've applied a simple update (via jQuery) of what i'm trying to accomplish here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3mJPy/

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
      $('#gallery li').each(function() {
        $(this).width($(this).find('img').width());
    });
});
```

As you can see, this demonstrates the initial request, notice the horizontal scrollbar size adjustment as well, this is perfect as i intend on using this as a horizontal scroller.  However, the issue remains now that we can't scale back to large since the containers now have sizes applied to them.

**::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::/ UPDATE::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::**

What I'd like to do is have a `<ul>` take up a percentage of the page height, so that when a user resizes the browser vertically it's contents (images) will scale. I'd like to keep images proportionate, and pushed to the left.

The problem I'm running into is that when resized vertically, the `<li>` seem to keep their initial size so that when scaled, there is now a gap between the image and it's container.

Test the fiddle here by grabbing the handle right above where it says "Top Area" and drag it down, you'll see the awkward spacing / gaps between the items.  However, if you refresh the page (Run) with the new gaps with the browser remembering where you dragged the frame, everything looks correct.

http://jsfiddle.net/qmUHN/

**Before resizing / pulling down frame:**

[image]

**After resizing / pulling down frame:**

[image]

Comment: Does removing `width:auto;` help?

Comment: No, that causes the images to squash (not proportional scaling) and the width for the container remains the same.  See fiddle here to try it yourself:  http://jsfiddle.net/qmUHN/

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You are scaling down the images proprortionaly as the height decreases, therefore their total width is going to decrease, yet their "container", the page width,  is not. Therefore you will have excess space. One option, float the `li` left so that all the empty space is to the right.

Comment: @JonP what I expect to happen is the result of when you refresh (Run) the page as mentioned after you resize the frame, you'll see what i'm talking about.  Float:left doesn't help, the gaps remain upon resizing.  I'm guessing my only option is to use Javascript to adjust on resize making the 'li' same width as it's child?

Comment: @JonP see updated question, I added a little javascript to demonstrate further.

Comment: @Joe: Is the code is expecting one or not.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, I hope this what you are expecting:

```
body {
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
#top {
    background:yellow;
    color:black;
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
ul#gallery {
    margin:0;
    height:auto;
    background:orange;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}

ul#gallery li {
    float:left;
    display:block;

}

ul#gallery li img {
    width:100%;
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qmUHN/3/)

Comment: No, check my updated answer.  Please see test what is happening with this demo to understand what I mean w/ the resizing of the frame:  http://jsfiddle.net/3mJPy/

Comment: I want the list items to remain inline and stretch it's container to flow outside the body if necessary.